# .htaccess rewrite rule page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If page name doesn't exist then I would like to show `page not found` instead of a blank white page.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ page.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

page.php:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name='$name'");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['content'];

}
```

If some of you know a better way, please share it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your PHP code like this:

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name');

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name='$name'")) {
   if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
      printf('404 / page Not Found');
      exit;
   }
   else {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row['content'];
      }
   }
} else {
   printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mysql num rows and make if it == 0 then show page not found before the while loop